# python random.choices() почему при выводе случайного булевого значения не добавляется значение в список

Tags: python

Почему метод random.choices() не добавляет новые значения в список.

```
import random

zoo = [1,2,3,4,5]

for item in zoo:
    b = random.choices([True, False], weights=[0.9, 0.1])
    if b == True:
        zoo.append(item)

print(zoo)
```

Comment: Потому что условие `if b == True:` никогда не выполнится. Вы пробовали посмотреть, что находится внутри `b`?

Comment: Коротко: `random.choices` ([документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)) возвращает список, вы этот список сравниваете с True. Никакой список не равен True, поэтому условие в if у вас никогда не выполняется.

Comment: Я так понял тогда необходимо прописать: b = bool(random.choices([True, False], weights=[0.9, 0.1])) для перевода в булевое значение?

Comment: И тогда `b` будет всегда равно `True`, потому что любой непустой список считается «истинным»

Comment: А что если попробовать перевести сначало True в строку, а потом уже в булевое значение?

Comment: берите первый элемент `random.choices(...)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) возвращает массив `[True]` или `[False]`:

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> import random
> @>>> random.choices([True, False], weights=[0.9, 0.1])
> [True]
> ```

А массив не бывает равным `True`:

> ```
> @>>> [True] == True
> False
> @>>> [False] == True
> False
> ```

Все проверки проваливаются, код не работает как ожидается.

Можно взять из массива первый элемент (`[0]` в конце строки):

```
    b = random.choices([True, False], weights=[0.9, 0.1])[0]
```

Можно взять из массива первый элемент c помощью *tuple destructuring assignment* (`,` в начале строки):

```
    b, = random.choices([True, False], weights=[0.9, 0.1])
```

Вам нужна истина с вероятностью *0.9*, иначе ложь. [random.random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) возвращает равномерно распределённые вещественные числа на полуинтервале *[0, 1)*. Отсюда классическое решение задачи:

```
    b = random.random() < 0.9
```

Совершенно случайно вероятность выражена рациональной дробью. Для дробей возможен трюк с [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange). Знаменатель дроби в скобках, числитель в правой части неравенства:

```
    b = random.randrange(10) < 9  # 9/10 probability
```

**P.S.** Вы меняете список по которому в данный момент происходит цикл. Это не хорошо, но в данном случае ничего ужасного не происходит - код будет работать так как вы ожидаете. Будьте осторожны:

```
import random


zoo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for item in zoo:
    if random.random() < 0.9:
        zoo.append(item)
print(len(zoo), ':', *zoo)
```

**P.P.S.** Или так:

```
import random


zoo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
zoo += (i for i in zoo if random.random() < 0.9)
print(len(zoo), ':', *zoo)
```

**P.P.P.S.** Я наконец понял что было нужно:

```
import random


zoo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
zoo += [i for i in zoo if random.random() < 0.9]
print(len(zoo), ':', *zoo)
```

Надеюсь, вы понимаете чем последний вариант отличается от предпоследнего.

Comment: последний вариант отличается от первого тем, что список изменяем. По идее кортеж не изменен

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Штука в круглых скобках - генератор, не кортеж. С круглыми скобками элементы будут вычисляться и сразу добавляться в список - список может получиться сколь угодно длинным. С квадратными скобками сперва вычислится правая часть длиной не более пяти элмементов и затем она добавится к исходному списку. Результат будет не более десяти элементов.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

zoo = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_zoo = []
for items in (zoo):
    a = random.choices([1, 0], weights=[0.9, 0.1])
    b = int(''.join(map(str,a)))
    c = bool(b)

    if c == True:
        new_zoo.append(items)

zoo += new_zoo

print(zoo)
print(new_zoo)
print(c, type(c))
```

В итоге нашел ответ, корректно работает теперь цикл. Прошу знающих людей указать как с точки зрения правильности написания кода указать как его написать локаничней, правильней и красивей =) Всем спасибо!

Comment: `zoo += [i for i in zoo if random.random() < 0.9]`.